# .Net Core, Stored Procedures and Connection Pooling

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, connection-pooling

I have a .NET Core Web API service that will call two stored procedures (and nothing else). I am wondering how to accomplish these calls in .NET Core.

At first I was thinking about using Entity Framework Core for my database connection. I was considering EF Core because I know it handles a lot of hard bits about connecting to the database (for example connection pooling).

But this service has some fairly strict performance requirements. I need it to be fast and be able to handle a fairly high amount of call traffic. To be honest, EF Core can probably handle it. But adding EF Core feels like I am adding a lot of complexity to something very simple.

So I thought I would ask, are there any other options in .NET Core for connecting to a SQL Server database in a safe, pooled, high traffic tolerant way?

A few side notes in case it is relevant:

- My service will have two operations
- Each operation will take 3 strings and an integer and call one of the two stored procedures
- It will return only true or false to both types of calls (returned from the stored procedure as a `bit`)

Comment: `To be honest, EF Core can probably handle it. But adding EF Core feels like I am adding a lot of complexity to something very simple.` If you do not want to perform complexity with EF, you can try to use [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) to access to your SQL db.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am calling procedure in .NET Core

```
try
{
    using (var db = new DBEntities())
    {
        var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<EmployeesData>("exec uspDataOfEmployee {0} , {1}", 
            EmployeeId , Convert.ToDateTime(month).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Instance.Error(ex, "Exceptio while calling procedureName( method.", EmployeeId.ToString());
    throw;
}
```

**List of benefits if you are using above code...**

1. Easy  to make this call async.
2. Easy to pass the parameters
3. Easy to map with your custom model
4. No need to generate the Complex Types to register the procedure and it's return type in EDMX file.
5. Obvious , fast response time.

Comment: Which version of .Net Core and EF Core are you using? I can't find Database.SqlQuery on .Net Core v3.1 EF Core v3.1.

Comment: I got this solution a long time back... But happy to see that somebody replied... With answer thanks bro

Comment: In EFCore v3.1, there's an alternative of the above method i.e. context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw() and this can only execute scaler queries/SPs. Scaler means the queries which return single value.